# How to resize an image with only the source URL, not the original file?

Tags: javascript, angular, image, image-processing

I'm honestly not sure if this is even possible, but after a few days of digging around on existing posts without yet finding a solution, I figured I'd ask the community here.

I'm developing a new frontend for a community-style website where users can upload their own posts, including images. Images are uploaded directly to an AWS S3 storage bucket, and then the source URL is stored in a database.

The previous development team did not use any sort of image optimization on initial upload, so when I'm receiving the S3 source URLs from our backend, the image size can range from small (300px widths) to massive (5000px widths). As a result, the frontend's feed of user posts has intermittent loading times as the browser takes time to load these massive images in the feed.

I'm wondering if there's any way I can do some nifty work to "resize" or otherwise optimize an image using only the source URL. From what I understand, in most cases I'd need the original file for any size optimizations, but maybe someone here knows a trick I'm overlooking.

I've attempted to take the source URLs and create a `canvas` that holds a down-stepped version of the original image, but haven't been successful here. I'm working with the latest version of Angular (8.x), and the images are inside an *ngFor loop, which makes this a little more challenging.

Comment: Nothing you do client side will cut down size delivered from source. You could intercept the url in your angular app and pass it to a server side optimizing script to return scaled image

Comment: per @charlietfl you would need to write a server side process to crawl, inspect and optimize. Alternatively you could write a new server side image handler that resizes on the fly. However as your server is no closer to the file this would be moot.

Comment: @charlietfl & Bibberty (won't let me tag again), thanks for confirming. i'll talk to our backend devs about this.

Answer (score 0):

This [aws solution](https://aws.amazon.com/solutions/serverless-image-handler/) seems like it would accomplish what you are after since you're already using S3. Looks like you could use the [resize](https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/en/stable/api-resize/#resize) method to resize your image.

Comment: thanks for the resource link! i'll see what we can do with this.